# How can I correctly set React-Leaflet map position through redux-toolkit state?

Tags: reactjs, redux, state, redux-toolkit, react-leaflet

I have to get the address I want to set as the leaflet position through redux. Problem is, when I do that, the map renders like this.[image]

```
import React, {useEffect} from "react";
import { Container } from "react-bootstrap";
import { fetchOrgData } from "../../features/about/aboutReducer";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, Marker, Popup, useMap } from 'react-leaflet'
import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css';

const ContactForm = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { orgData } = useSelector(state => state.about);
  const position = orgData.address;
  console.log(position)
```

`console.log(position)` returns [-34.55881726737178, -58.47476996280374] just so you know that state is well called.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchOrgData());
  }, [dispatch]);

return (
    <Container
      className="d-flex flex-column justify-content-center text-center p-3"
    >
    <h1>Contacto</h1> 
    <MapContainer
        center={position}
        zoom={13} 
        scrollWheelZoom={false} 
        style={{ height: "450px", width: "100%" }}
     >
        <TileLayer
            attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
            url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
        />
        <Marker 
            position={position}>
        </Marker>
    </MapContainer>
</Container>
  );
};
```

However, if I hard-code the "position" value to the leaflet prop, the map renders correctly.

```
<MapContainer
        center={[-34.55881726737178, -58.47476996280374]}
        zoom={13} 
        scrollWheelZoom={false} 
        style={{ height: "450px", width: "100%" }}
     >
        <TileLayer
            attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
            url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
        />
        <Marker 
            position={[-34.55881726737178, -58.47476996280374]}>
        </Marker>
    </MapContainer>
```

[image]

This probably has to do with the "orgData" state value not being called soon enough for the map to render correctly with its value. So, how should I proceed to fix this?

Comment: Could you create a demo with what you have so far?

Answer (score 1):

You will want to create a ref for the map

```js
const mapRef = useRef();
<Map ref={mapRef}/>
```

Then access the underlying leaflet map to `setView` or `flyTo` when the redux selector updates

```js
useEffect(() => {
    const zoomLevel = 5;
    mapRef.current.leafletElement.flyTo(orgData.address, zoomLevel);
}, [orgData.address]);
```